# Bibliography in two columns, section title in one

Tags: bibliographies, two-column, multicol

I'm using the following to span the bibliography to two columns:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{multicols}
```

Yet, the section title (`"References"` in the article document style) also appear as part of the two columns, while I want it to span the whole page.
How can I do something equivalent to the following code, but still using BibTeX?

```
\section*{References}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\thebibliography{..}
\end{multicols}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building upon Gonzalo's answer, I suggest to use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to selectively change the definitions of `\thebibliography` and `\endthebibliography`. Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}
    {\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\refname}]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endthebibliography}{\endlist}{\endlist\end{multicols}}{}{}
```

EDIT: How does it work? The `\patchcmd` command needs five arguments, but you may ignore (as I did) the two last ones, which generate patching success/error messages. Argument no. 1 is the command to be "patched" (selectively changed), argument no. 2 is the part of the command definition that should be replaced, argument no. 3 is the replacement. (Because `thebibliography` is an environment, I had to patch the two commands that define it.)

Comment: Patching using `\section*{\refname}` has the problem that the solution does not work for `report` or `book` classes. You can use `\list` as the search pattern and replace it with `{\list\begin{multicols}{2}}`.

Comment: @Guido True, but I prefer to use `multicols` optional second argument because I've had some trouble with regard to spacing if I start `multicols` after sectioning commands.

Answer (score 9):

You can redefine the `thebibliography` environment to use two columns and use the optional argument of `multicols` to place the title; add the following lines to the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\refname}]%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist\end{multicols}}
\makeatother
```

Now in the body of your document, simply use

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{mybib}
```

Comment: Works great.. but it is unfortunate to need to redefine everything. I like the solution of lockstep for its brevity (although I am not sure I yet understand how it works)

Comment: @Ran G. my solution doesn't redefine everything; it only changes two lines in the original definition of the `thebibliography` environment; lockstep's solution does exactly what I did, but with the help of a package. The idea in both cases is to make two replacements in the original definition: 1) Instead of `\section*{\refname}`
use `\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\refname}]` and 2) Instead of `\endlist` use `\endlist\end{multicols}`.

Comment: thanks for the explanations. Since I don't really understand the internals I try to avoid low-level hacks (that is, anything that begins with \makeatletter, etc :)

Comment: How do you with your method change the name from `References` to e.g. `Bibliography` ?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen there are a number of questions in this site addressing this issue. Depends on whether you use `babel` or not. Without `babel`: `\renewcommand\refname{The New Name}`, with `babel` you need `\addto\captions<language>{\renewcommand\refname{The New Name}}`, where `<language>` is the main language declared.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `natbib`, The easiest way to tackle this problem is to use `bibpreamble` and `bibpostamble`:

```
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand{\bibpostamble}{\end{multicols}}
```

In this manner, only the references are placed in two columns and your title is left out. Nevertheless, it keeps the heading of the bibliography in the `chapter`-style. To change that, you could use e.g. `bibsection`:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\renewcommand\bibsection{\section{\bibname}}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could add compilable code? It would be easier for other people to test your solution.

Comment: This seems neater than the other answers, and works for me.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found to have references in two columns is to use `\twocolumn` command like this:

```
\twocolumn
\bibliography{report}
\onecolumn
```

Comment: It seems that this solution yields an empty second column in each frame of the bibliography...