# Bibliography spacing with BibLaTeX (and two columns)

Tags: spacing, biblatex, multicol

I need to fine tune the distances marked as A, B, C and D in the figure below. Any suggestions?

In particular, I would like B=0pt, and the other three to be small.

I am using BibLaTeX and two columns:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{multicol}
...
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{multicols}
```

[image: Distances]

Comment: For length "B", keep in mind that it includes the space for an additional figure.

Answer (score 9):

For the sake of completeness: If one wanted to typeset the bibliography in two-column mode, but to leave the bibliography heading as a single column, here's how to do it:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}[\printbibheading]
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: In order to work, doesn't this needs a `\defbibheading{none}{}` in the preamble?

Comment: @henrique: No, because a definition of the bibliography heading `none` was added in biblatex v1.5.

Comment: Could you consider cross-posting this answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20758/37357)? It's a *lot* simpler than the existing answers there.

Answer (score 4):

Everything can be tweaked by playing with the lengths and counters defined by biblatex, see ***§ 3.8.3 Lengths and Counters*** of the biblatex documentation, which explains everything clearly. 
`\bibhang` treats both B and D, while `\biblabelsep` treats C. 
For the A factor, it is linked to the style of the bibliography heading.

Comment: D is actually the sum of B and `\columnsep`.

Comment: Right, I think I have worked out how to fiddle with the parameters. So far my choice of parameters is rather ad-hoc, but it will do for now.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, here is a working solution where various parameters are included. Note that \columnsep is set at the bottom.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
    % To make biber work:
    \makeatletter
    \providecommand\bibstyle@faked{}
    \providecommand\bibdata@faked{}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\noexpand\bibstyle@faked}%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\noexpand\bibdata@faked}}
    \makeatother

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
    {\list
        {\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}
        {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{10pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{4pt}
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}
        \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}

    \blindtext \nocite{*}

    \setlength{\columnsep}{12pt}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
        \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```