# Using BibTeX, how can I make the bibliography multicolumn?

Tags: bibliographies, multicol

Since my bibligraphy stretches over several pages I would like to make only these pages multicolum (2 columns) and maybe also make their text size a bit smaller than the document standard.

How is this possible?

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bibliography in two columns, section title in one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20758/bibliography-in-two-columns-section-title-in-one)

Comment: I believe this is not an _exact_ duplicate since here the text is made smaller as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple way is to load the `multicol` package and then use

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\bibliography{<bibfile>}
\end{multicols}
```

EDIT: A problem with the above solution is that **References** appears in the first column, at the same level as the bibliography. For the standard classes, a (better) alternative is the following:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{relsize}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\list}
  {\begin{multicols}{2}\smaller\list}
  {}
  {}
\appto{\endthebibliography}{\end{multicols}}
```

and then use the standard way in which you insert your bibliography.

In this way the (section) heading for the reference/bibliography appears before starting  the columns.

Different classes might need different patches.

Comment: `\begin{multicols}{2}\smaller ...` after loading `\usepackage{relsize}` ;)

Comment: Using your first suggestion worked perfect in `report`. Also, using `relsize` with `\smaller` made it look amazing.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen With `report` it can produce very bad results.

Comment: hmm, okey. But your second solution; how do you specify which bibliography file to be used? I have only used bibtex for my references

Comment: `\thebibliography` is called internally by `\bibliography{<bibfile>}`. So you do not have to change anything, Just use `\bibliography{<bibfile(s)>}