# Change the lay-out of the bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I just started a major project which presumably will grow up to 70 pages, including quite some for my bibliography. So I want that to look neat and orderly.

Until now, I have been satisfied with the default outcome of `\usepackage[round,sort]{natbib}`, `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`, but I have ever wanted to change it. What I would like the thing to look like in the end is (text between slashes should be *in italics*, caps should be small caps):

```
AUTHOR, F.O.
    2000 - /This is my First Book/, Address: Publisher

SCHREIBER, K.
    1802 - /Wenn Wir Auf Deutsch Geschrieben Habe/, Address: Publisher
    1803 - 'Ich weiss nicht wie das heisst', in: Etwas, E. (ed.), /Das Buch/, Address: Publisher, pp. 5-6
```

It would be nice to be able to put in two columns. But I don't know what the options are.
Is this possible? Or is this not an option in latex and do I have to accept it the way it is?

Here's the output generated by the basic `agsm` bibliography style; note that it differs in several ways from the preferred style laid out above.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[round,sort]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibl}
\end{document}
```

`bibl.bib` file:

```
@book{auth00,
author={Author, First One},
title={This is my First Book},
year={2000},
publisher={Publisher},
address={Address}}

@book{schr02,
author={Schreiber, Kugel},
title={Wenn Wir Auf Deutsch Geschrieben Habe},
year={1802},
publisher={Publisher},
address={Address}}

@incollection{schr03,
author={Schreiber, Kugel},
title={Ich weiss nicht wie das heisst},
year={1803},
booktitle={Das Buch},
editor={Etwas, Edward},
publisher={Publisher},
address={Address}}
```

Comment: Do you want to continue using the `agsm` bibliography style? (I didn't think that this style introduces a line break between the author's name(s) and the subsequent bibliographic information...)

Comment: you should look to biblatex-package. It's the best to have customized bibliography.

Comment: @Maïeul - Is there a predefined biblatex style that reproduces the output of the `agsm` style?

Comment: Please give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @Mico : i don't know, but all is possible.

Comment: @Maïeul - How helpful is it to suggest a switch to `biblatex` unless such a suggestion is accompanied by specific advice regarding implementing all components of a specific 'look' (such as the one generated by the `agsm` style)? I have absolutely nothing against `biblatex`, by the way. I'm mostly concerned that a generic piece of advice ("switch to biblatex, it's highly customizable") may go over well unless it's accompanied by additional, style-specific advice.

Comment: @Mico that why it was not an answer, but just a remark. I don't know the agsm bibliography style, so I can't answer more. I just send a pist.

Comment: @Mico I'm not unwilling to try something totally different, but this is what I have used the last two years. I sorted out what the best option was for me at that time, but I don't really know all the reasons I have.

Comment: I would second @Maïeul's recommendation just switched to `biblatex` because I was fed up trying to work out how to get a style I liked with bibtex/natbib. I found it quite painless and I made the switch and set up exactly the style I wanted in a couple of hours. I have no idea about the two columns, but it sounds like the sort of thing that ought to be possible

Comment: @Maïeul If you can explain me how this can be achieved with Biblatex, including Harvard-like style of citing, I'm not unwilling to get acquainted with it.

Comment: AFAICT, you want to make five changes: (i) "Address: Publisher" instead of "Publisher, Address", (ii) "in: Editor, E. Etwas" instead of "*in* E. Etwas, ed.,"; (iii) `title` field of `@incollection`-type entries should be surrounded by single quotes; (iv) `booktitle` field of `@incollection`-type entries should be set in italics rather than be surrounded by single quotes; and (v) no `.` at the end of every entry. Please confirm or correct.

Comment: All correct, except (ii); that was an error in my example. The main problem, however, is that entries should be listed by year under the authors name. This makes it much easier to find something in bibliographies of several pages (earlier essays had a ratio 3:1 of text:bibliography). The features you listed are not the most important changes.

Comment: Would you be OK replacing repeated author names with triple em-dashes? That would be much easier to program than line breaks and indentations.

Comment: For the bibliography in two columns see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77983/16895

Comment: To organise bibliographies per authors (using biblatex) see  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83891/16895

Comment: Well, I shifted to Biblatex, succeeded to get the author/editor in the bibliography in small caps, got the bibliography organised per authors, and abandoned the idea of two columns. Now one step remains: replacing the numbers of the counter with the years of publication. I tried several things, but I just don't get how to get them at the exact same spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an adjustment of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83891/16895) for this question

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{fruits,
  title = {The apple and the banana},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor = {Straw Berry},
  author = {Annoying Orange},
  year = {1970}
}
@book{fruits2,
  title = {The pineapple and the banana},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor = {Straw Berry},
  author = {Annoying Orange},
  year = {1971}
}
@book{fruits3,
  title = {The mangos and the banana and other tropical fruits},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor = {Straw Berry},
  author = {Annoying Orange and Peachy Pear},
  year = {1970}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[firstinits,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@currentauthor}{}
\newcommand{\@current}{}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \savename{labelname}{\@current}%
  \ifdefstrequal{\@currentauthor}{\@current}
    {\par}
    {\item[]%
      \printnames[last-first/first-last]{labelname}\par}%
    \usedriver{}{special}%
    \makebox[0em][r]{\printfield{labelyear}\addspace--\addspace}%
    \clearfield{year}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{special}{%
\savename{labelname}{\@currentauthor}%
}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro{editor+others}{}
\renewbibmacro{author/translator+others}{}
\renewbibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}{}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
    {}
    {\setlength{\itemindent}{-4em}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{4em}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {}


\begin{document}
Hello world \cite{fruits,fruits2,fruits3}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

producing

[image]

For a version where the bibliography is over two column, load the `multicols` and `relsize` packages (i.e., `\usepackage{mulitcols,relksize}`) and then use the following (re)definition of  the `bibliography` environment:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{multicols}{2}\smaller\list
    {}
    {\setlength{\itemindent}{-4.5em}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{4.5em}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist\end{multicols}}
  {}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: Great! This is almost exactly what I needed. However, in cases where there are two publications by the same author in the same year it is necessary to distinguish between them in the bibliography. I changed \printfield{labelyear} to \printedateextra