# Two column nomenclature

Tags: two-column, nomenclature

I want to achieve [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20761/14819) for my nomenclature, making it two column with title on top of the columns and not part of the first one. I also want to keep my nomenclature's name changed to `Appendix` which I do with  `\renewcommand{\nomname}{Acronyms}`.

Can anyone help me "port" the code in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20761/14819) to my needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `\nomname` I guess you're using the `nomencl` package.

Then

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{chapter}
  {\def\wilh@nomsection{section}}
  {\def\wilh@nomsection{chapter}}

\def\thenomenclature{%
  \begin{multicols}{2}[%
    \csname\wilh@nomsection\endcsname*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{\wilh@nomsection}{\nomname}\fi
    \nompreamble]
  \list{}{%
    \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \itemsep\nomitemsep
    \let\makelabel\nomlabel}%
}
\def\endthenomenclature{%
  \endlist
  \end{multicols}
  \nompostamble}
\makeatother
```

should do.

Complete example (with mock nomenclature entries)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{chapter}
  {\def\wilh@nomsection{section}}
  {\def\wilh@nomsection{chapter}}

\def\thenomenclature{%
  \begin{multicols}{2}[%
    \csname\wilh@nomsection\endcsname*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{\wilh@nomsection}{\nomname}\fi
    \nompreamble]
  \list{}{%
    \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \itemsep\nomitemsep
    \let\makelabel\nomlabel}%
}
\def\endthenomenclature{%
  \endlist
  \end{multicols}
  \nompostamble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter    
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{X}

\newcount\pippo
\def\mocknom{\expandafter\nomenclature\expandafter{\romannumeral\pippo}{X}}

abc

\loop\ifnum\pippo<200
\advance\pippo1
\mocknom
\repeat

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get two columns within one column, and the nomenclature won't continue to the next page when filled: [my output](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9Lnsj9U0mK8Rmx1azhOYWQ0RUE) Also, I am using `report` if that matter

Comment: @Wilhelmsen Are you perhaps using the `twocolumn` option?

Comment: thank you, I hadn't removed my previous tests to get this working, making it a double two column. Thank you very much!

Comment: Now I don't have the ability to use sub-floats, I get hundreds of error messages. Removing your code solves the problem. What could this be?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen Without an example of code it's very hard to tell something.

Comment: I added a follow up question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81631/two-column-nomenclature-breaks-ability-to-have-sub-floats

Comment: @egreg  This code works very well in making a two-columns nomenclature in a   `\documentclass[10pt,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}`  document.  However, I have a `\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}` document. When I use your code, a nomenclature in two columns is shown up in one column of my paper. How can I modify your code so that a two-columns nomenclature shows up, and  each column of nomenclature is put in one column of my two-columns document?

Comment: @Mahdi I don't understand: in a two column document you have nothing special to do; just use the standard setting.