# How to make two column nomenclature, one column with symbols the other with subscripts?

Tags: multicol, nomenclature

I’ve created two columns in my nomenclature using `\multicols` my problem is how to split the columns. What I want is to have the left column be symbols, and the right column to be subscripts. Is there also a way to title both columns? Code is below:

```
    \section*{ } %Introduction  SECTION
    \begin{multicols}{2} %Add symbols here
    \nomenclature{\textit{P}}{Pressure}
    \nomenclature{\textit{T}}{Ambient or Atmospheric Temperature}
    \nomenclature{\textit{$F_{design}$}}{Design Load on Joint $(N)$}
    \nomenclature{\textit{$\mu_{F_{max}}$}}{Average Maximum Joint Strength $(N)$}
    \nomenclature{\textit{$\rho$}}{Density}
    \nomenclature{\textit{V}}{Velocity}
    \nomenclature{\textit{R}}{Universal Gas Constant}
    \columnbreak %Add subscripts here
    \nomenclature{\textit{atm}}{Atmospheric or Ambient}
    \nomenclature{\textit{1}}{Settling Chamber}
    \nomenclature{\textit{2}}{Test Section}
    \printnomenclature[\nomwidest]
    \end{multicols}
    \pagebreak
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78764/two-column-nomenclature?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to confuse the definitions of the nomenclature entries with the printing of them. `\nomenclature` only defines an entry, so it doesn't make sense to put them inside a `multicols` environment. You usually put these at the page where the item is defined. Also the `\columnbreak` doesn't do anything related to the printing of the nimenclature for the same reason. Al the formatting/printing will happen inside the `\printnomenclature` command, so there's where the action should be. Also before printing you have to process the entries with `makeindex`, which sorts the entries. So if they must be collected in two groups you must make sure that the sorting gathers them in these groups. You do this by giving an optional argument to `\nomenclature` that defines the group of the entry. The first letter of these optional argument should be different for the two groups. I chose `sy` and `xu` but it's not very important what you choose. The first letters should be different and the alphabetical order determines the order of the groups in the output. Then you define a macros `\nomgroup`, that gets as parameter the first letter, capitalized (so S and X). Then we use this to format the group labels. S will be use to print 'Symbols' and X will be used to do the columnbreak and print 'Subscripts. And we put the multicols stuff in the preamble and postamble. By the way, if you want to change the order of the entries you can put some extra stuff in the optional argument, because that will be used for the sorting.

So here is a working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\large\textbf{Symbols}]}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{\columnbreak\item[\large\textbf{Subscripts}]}{}}}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand{\nompostamble}{\end{multicols}}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

   \nomenclature[sy ]{\textit{P}}{Pressure}
    \nomenclature[sy ]{\textit{T}}{Ambient or Atmospheric Temperature}
    \nomenclature[sy ]{\textit{$F_{design}$}}{Design Load on Joint $(N)$}
    \nomenclature[sy ]{\textit{$\mu_{F_{max}}$}}{Average Maximum Joint Strength $(N)$}
    \nomenclature[sy ]{\textit{$\rho$}}{Density}
    \nomenclature[sy ]{\textit{V}}{Velocity}
    \nomenclature[sy ]{\textit{R}}{Universal Gas Constant}
    \nomenclature[xu ]{\textit{atm}}{Atmospheric or Ambient}
    \nomenclature[xu ]{\textit{1}}{Settling Chamber}
    \nomenclature[xu ]{\textit{2}}{Test Section}

     \printnomenclature

\end{document}
```