# How to eliminate number labels from two-column bibliography

Tags: bibtex, labels, multicol

I found a code snippet for a two-column bibliography in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20761/224972):

```
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\refname}]%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist\end{multicols}}
\makeatother
```

This basically does what I want (i.e. is in two columns, so takes up less space) except that each item is preceded by [1], [2], ...
Since I'm using the bibliography in `moderncv` I don't really need labels since there are no citations in the text.  If labels are hard to avoid, I'd prefer something like a bullet.

I guess this might make things more compicated, but for better or worse I am currently using [plainyr-rev.bst](https://github.com/jberger/Curriculum_Vita/blob/master/plainyr-rev.bst) also. That's not vital though; the bblography only contains a dozen or so items and I could just change the labels and sort by those, probably.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. What happens when you comment out `\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}`? What have you tried out so far?

Comment: That does it, thanks, if you would like to provide that as an answer I would be pleased to accept it.

Comment: You can self-answer and self-accept. Speculative guessing on my part isn't guaranteed to be workable. Also, you demonstrated the solution worked. Plus, I don't have your setup, so could never have tested anything anyway. Good to hear it's solved, though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20758/bibliography-in-two-columns-section-title-in-one/20761#20761) which I linked in the question provides most of the functionality I need, and with the tweak suggested by [Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada) does what I want.   So, I ended up with this:

```
\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\boolean{twocolbib}}{
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\refname}]%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{}
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist\end{multicols}}
}{}
\makeatother
```

As things turned out though, other parts of my resume got long enough that it no longer fitted on one page anyway, so the advantage of a two-column bibliography went away, and so I added an `\ifthenelse` in case I needed it again.