# How to condense references maximally

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, multicol

I would like to condense the references in my dissertation since they count towards the page limit. As things stand they look like this:

[image]

whereas I was looking for something more compact like this:

[image]
or the single column equivalent if that saves more space. The only constraint is that the fontsize must be no smaller than 10pt.

Here is my main tex file and .bib sample for a WE.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}        % Warns for incorrect (obsolete) LaTeX usage

% UoB guidelines for thesis presentation were found at:
% http://www.bristol.ac.uk/academic-quality/pg/pgrcode/annex4/
%
% Memoir class loads useful packages by default (see manual).
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,reqno,openbib,oldfontcommands,openany]{memoir} %add 'draft' to turn draft option on (see below)
%
%
% Adding metadata:
\let\ordinal\relax %to avoid warning with datetime and memoir
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\pdfinfo{
   /Author (Author's name)
   /Title (PhD Thesis)
   /Keywords (One; Two;Three)
   /CreationDate (D:\pdfdate)
}
\fi
% When draft option is on. 
\ifdraftdoc 
    \usepackage{draftwatermark}             %Sets watermarks up.
    \SetWatermarkScale{0.3}
    \SetWatermarkText{\bf Draft: \today}
\fi
%
%
% Better page layout for A4 paper, see memoir manual.
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth} 
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth} 
\settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*} 
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5} 
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout
%
\frenchspacing

%
% UoB guidelines:
%
% font size should be
% chosen to ensure clarity and legibility for the main text and for any
% quotations and footnotes. Margins should allow for eventual hard binding.
%
%
% Sets numbering division level
\setsecnumdepth{subsection} 
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
%
%
% UoB guidelines:
%
% The pages should be numbered consecutively at the bottom centre of the
% page.
\makepagestyle{myvf} 
\makeoddfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeevenfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeheadrule{myvf}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 
\makeevenhead{myvf}{\small\textsc{\leftmark}}{}{} 
\makeoddhead{myvf}{}{}{\small\textsc{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{myvf}
%

% \newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
%

% commands to change the chapter heading layout to save whitespace
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{} % zero space before
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\enspace}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vspace{\onelineskip}} % one blank line after



% Creates index for Table of Contents, List of Figures, List of Tables and Index
\makeindex
% \printglossaries below creates a list of abbreviations. \gls and related
% commands are then used throughout the text, so that latex can automatically
% keep track of which abbreviations have already been defined in the text.
%
% The import command enables each chapter tex file to use relative paths when
% accessing supplementary files. For example, to include
% chapters/brewing/images/figure1.png from chapters/brewing/brewing.tex we can
% use
% \includegraphics{images/figure1}
% instead of
% \includegraphics{chapters/brewing/images/figure1}
\usepackage{import}

% Add other packages needed for chapters here. For example:
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   %Calls Amer. Math. Soc. (AMS) fonts
\usepackage{amsmath}            %Writes maths centred down
\usepackage{stmaryrd}                   %New AMS symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}                    %Calls AMS symbols
\usepackage{amsthm}                 %Calls AMS theorem environment
\usepackage{newlfont}                   %Helpful package for fonts and symbols
\usepackage{layouts}                    %Layout diagrams
\usepackage{graphicx}                   %Calls figure environment
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         %Needed to encode non-english characters 
\usepackage{subfig}                     %for subfigures
\usepackage{float}                      %Helps to place figures, tables, etc. 
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}       %Calls bibliography commands 

\usepackage{url}                        %Supports url commands
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}     %For languages characters and hyphenation

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
             allcolors=black]{hyperref}              %Creates hyperlinks in cross references
\usepackage{memhfixc}                   %Must be used on memoir document 
                                    %class after hyperref
\usepackage{enumerate}                  %For enumeration counter
\usepackage{footnote}                   %For footnotes
\usepackage{microtype}                  %Makes pdf look better.
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}          %PGF/TikZ is a tandem of languages for producing vector graphics from a 
\usepackage{siunitx}                    % Allows writing of SI units
\newcommand{\diff}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}{#1}}{\mathrm{d}{#2}}}     % differential notation
\newcommand{\ddiff}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^2{#1}}{\mathrm{d}{#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\pdiff}[2]{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}}

\usepackage{tikz}                       % Enables circled text
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
            
            
%Reduce widows  (the last line of a paragraph at the start of a page) and orphans 
% (the first line of paragraph at the end of a page)
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000
%
% New command definitions for my thesis
%
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\noindent{\small{\bf Keywords:} #1}} %Defines keywords small section
%
%
%
\usepackage{subcaption}
%
\usepackage{xcolor}
%Creates coloured text and background
\definecolor{UniversityRed}{RGB}{171,31,45}
%Defines user-defined colour (Univeristy of Bristol Red here)
%
% Theorem styles used in my thesis
%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lemma}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{resu}{Result}[chapter]
%
%
%
\begin{document}
% UoB guidlines:
%
% Preliminary pages
% 
% The five preliminary pages must be the Title Page, Abstract, Dedication
% and Acknowledgements, Author's Declaration and Table of Contents.
% These should be single-sided.
% 
% Table of contents, list of tables and illustrative material
% 
% The table of contents must list, with page numbers, all chapters,
 % sections and subsections, the list of references, bibliography, list of
% abbreviations and appendices. The list of tables and illustrations
% should follow the table of contents, listing with page numbers the
% tables, photographs, diagrams, etc., in the order in which they appear
% in the text.
% 
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
%
\input{frontmatter/title}
% \clearemptydoublepage
%
\input{frontmatter/abstract}
% \clearemptydoublepage
%
\input{frontmatter/dedication}
% \clearemptydoublepage
%
\input{frontmatter/declaration}
% \clearemptydoublepage
%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents*
\addtocontents{toc}{\par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\bf Page}\par\nobreak}
% \clearemptydoublepage
%
\listoftables
\addtocontents{lot}{\par\nobreak\textbf{{\scshape Table} \hfill Page}\par\nobreak}
% \clearemptydoublepage
%
\listoffigures
\addtocontents{lof}{\par\nobreak\textbf{{\scshape Figure} \hfill Page}\par\nobreak}
% \clearemptydoublepage
%
%
% The bulk of the document is delegated to these chapter files in
% subdirectories.
\mainmatter
%
\import{chapters/chap.1 Intro}{chap.1Intro.tex}


\import{chapters/chap.2 Literature Review}{chap.2LiteratureReview.tex}

\import{chapters/chap.3 Methodology}{chap.3Methodology.tex}

\import{chapters/chap.4 Results}{chap.4Results.tex}

\import{chapters/chap.5 Discussion}{chap.5Discussion.tex}


% And the appendix goes here
\appendix
\import{chapters/appendices/}{app0A.tex}
% \clearemptydoublepage
%
% Apparently the guidelines don't say anything about citations or
% bibliography styles so I guess we can use anything.

\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\bibliography{thesisbiblio.bib}
% \clearemptydoublepage
%
% Add index
%\printindex
%   
\end{document}
```

bib sample:

```
@Book{Izhikevich2007,
  author    = {Izhikevich, Eugene},
  publisher = {MIT Press},
  title     = {Dynamical systems in neuroscience : the geometry of excitability and bursting},
  year      = {2007},
  address   = {Cambridge, Mass},
  isbn      = {9780262090438},
}

@article{Lewicki1998,
   author = {Michael S Lewicki},
   doi = {10.1088/0954-898X_9_4_001},
   issn = {0954-898X},
   issue = {4},
   journal = {Network: Computation in Neural Systems},
   month = {1},
   title = {A review of methods for spike sorting: the detection and classification of neural action potentials},
   volume = {9},
   year = {1998},
}

}

@article{Gollisch2008,
   author = {Tim Gollisch and Markus Meister},
   doi = {10.1126/science.1149639},
   issn = {0036-8075},
   issue = {5866},
   journal = {Science},
   month = {2},
   title = {Rapid Neural Coding in the Retina with Relative Spike Latencies},
   volume = {319},
   year = {2008},
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just learn how to make double columned pages? https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns

Comment: Don't use the `openbib` document class option, and each bib entry will occupy much less space.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
    \bibmark \ifnobibintoc \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\bibname }\fi
    \prebibhook
  }%
  \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}%
  \setlength{\bibsep}{\medskipamount}%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\begin{multicols}{2}[\chapter{\bibname}]}
\AtEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{\end{multicols}}
```

If you also remove `openbib` you save even more space.

[image]

With the `openbib` option you get this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [Bibliography in two columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20761/161015):

Redefine the `thebibliography` environment to use two columns and use the optional argument of `multicols` to place the title.

Add  to the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
{\begin{multicols}{2}[\chapter*{\refname}]%
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
        \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
        {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
        \sloppy
        \clubpenalty4000
        \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
        \widowpenalty4000%
        \sfcode`\.\@m}
    {\def\@noitemerr
        {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
        \endlist\end{multicols}}
\makeatother
```

[image: a]

(Your example uses bibtex not biblatex)